# Can't read memory of a struct allocated by CoTaskMemAlloc

Tags: c++, com, ole

I have the following problem.

I am implementing an `IDataObject`, which is responsible for passing files to the Clipboard. When I call `GetData` on my `IDataObject` it seems to return an empty `STGMEDIUM` struct with unreadable memory, although I could confirm that the struct was filled with the correct values through a breakpoint. This is my code:

Call to GetData:

```
FORMATETC dsl_form={//some FORMATETC};
STGMEDIUM *dsl_med = {0};

HRESULT hr;
hr=dsp_in->GetData(&dsl_form, dsl_med);
```

The GetData-Function:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE GetData(FORMATETC *dsp_fmt,STGMEDIUM *dsp_med) {
    int iml_idx=m_lookup_format(dsp_fmt);//Search the FORMATETC-Array for a Format that equals the given Format
    //If no suitable FormatEtc was found, report an error
    if(iml_idx<0){
        return DV_E_FORMATETC;
    }
    //Allocate and fill a new STGMEDIUM structure
    dsp_med=(STGMEDIUM*) CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof STGMEDIUM);
    dsp_med->tymed=dsc_filedesc[iml_idx].tymed;
    dsp_med->pUnkForRelease=0;
    switch(dsc_filedesc[iml_idx].tymed) {
    case TYMED_HGLOBAL:     dsp_med->hGlobal=m_dup_global_mem(dsc_filecontents[iml_idx].hGlobal);
                            break;
    default:                return DV_E_FORMATETC;
    }

    return S_OK;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
STGMEDIUM *dsl_med = {0};

HRESULT hr;
hr=dsp_in->GetData(&dsl_form, dsl_med);
```

copies null `dsl_med` into function parameter, the function called changes the copy passed to it, but the original null value is unchanged so the pointer on the caller side remains null.

One option would be to change the function signature so that it accepts `STGMEDIUM**` and alter the rest of the code accordingly. However in this case - when implementing `IDataObject::GetData()` - you cannot change the signature. If you read MSDN description it explains that the function should only allocate the stuff it assigns to the members of the structure, and the caller has to allocate the structure and optionally free its members.

So you have to pass the address of the struct

```
STGMEDIUM dsl_med = {0};
object->GetData(&dsl_from, &dsl_med);
```

and inside the function you just set the structure members.

Comment: Sadly that's impossible since I have to adhere to the Interface IDataObject which states that is has to be like this: HRESULT GetData(
  [in]   FORMATETC *pformatetcIn,
  [out]  STGMEDIUM *pmedium
);

Comment: And as far as I understood C++, I am handing the GetData-Method a copy of a pointer, the target of the pointer should still be the same, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you were trying to change the value passed inside the function and that change wouldn't propagate back. You were passing a null pointer, the null would be changed to non-null but the caller would only see the original null.